# Doubly connected Lorentz group?

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology, manifolds, lie-groups, connectedness

It is said that Lorentz group $O(1,3)$ is a six-dimensional noncompact non-abelian real Lie group that is not connected. The four connected components are not simply connected, but rather doubly connected. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_group#Basic_properties

What is the definition of the doubly connected?
Does it mean that $\pi_2(O(1,3))=0$?

Comment: In fact, $\pi_2(G) = 0$ for all Lie groups $G$: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/8957/homotopy-groups-of-lie-groups (David Treumann's answer there probably requires the least machinery to understand.)

Answer (score 3):

In this context, "doubly connected" means that $\pi_1$ is a group of order $2$. $SO^{+}(1, 3)$ has universal cover the indefinite [spin group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_group) $\text{Spin}(1, 3)$, which turns out to be isomorphic to $SL_2(\mathbb{C})$.

This isn't great terminology because, as you say, it can be misread as meaning [$2$-connected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-connected_space), which means that (the space is path-connected and) both $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ vanish. Some people also use "$n$-tuply connected" to mean that there are $n$ path components; I would avoid that terminology too.

Comment: I'm gonna edit the Wikipedia article.

Comment: I edited the Wikipedia article.